# Where does my pg_dump file go?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am trying to back up my database and have spent a good hour trying to find the file I'm creating.

Using the command prompt

```
pg_dump -U postgres mydb
```

If I try specify a location

```
pg_dump -U postgres mydb > "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\backup"
```

It says Access Denied

Answer (score 2):

Without specifying an output file, your dump should be going to standard out.

As for the example writing to the desktop - does your OS user have permissions to write to that location? If so, you should post exactly what you are running and your exact error message.

Also, rather than using redirection, you can use the `-f` flag to pass in the where the output file should be created. I highly recommend reading through [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html) for pg_dump.

Comment: Where is 'standard out'? (windows 7 64bit). I'm using the postgres user for psql, my account for Windows 7 has write access to desktop, how do I make this true for postgres user in psql?